# CCNet unable to sometime execute svn.exe

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I have ccNet running fine under windows server2008. However, from time to time I get this error: System.IO.IOException: Unable to execute file [C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe]. The file may not exist or may not be executable. (The directory name is invalid) --->

I can immediately "Force" the build again and then it runs fine. We have about 8 project running in CCnet and they all share quite a bit of common code and this problem usually happens when code is changed in the common part and all the builds kick off at about the same time. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: It looks like your error relates to your working directory, not the path to svn.exe; are you able to check what the working directory should be and if it could be deleted by another build?

Comment: Ah, you could be on to something Simon. I am also using the same workspace to "Force" Release builds whenever we need it, but I can't recall if ever I was doing a release build and a CI build on the same workspace at the same time....but it is definitely possible. I will keep an eye on it. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? As I'm getting this error as well.